# Translate Prototype code into Jquery version

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, prototypejs

I everybody,
I'm working on a SaaS application and I need to use Jquery instead of Prototype due to some extra plugins integration. My code that was wotking a charm with Prototype is not running anymore with Jquery and I'm not used to write in this framework...
Is there someone to help me in "translating" this one:
Thanks a lot for your help.

```
var rates = new Array();

<% for tva_rate in @tva_rates -%>

  rates.push(new Array(<%= tva_rate.id %>, '<%=h tva_rate.taux %>', '<%=h tva_rate.compte_id %>' ));

<% end -%>

function tvaSelected() {


  tva_id = $('journal_tva_id').getValue();

  show = 1;
  if (tva_id > 0){
    rates.each(function(rate) {
        if (rate[0] == tva_id) {
            $('journal_taux').setValue(rate[1]);
            $('journal_compte_tva').setValue(rate[2]);
            show = 2;
        }
    });
}

  if (show == 1) {
    $('tva_taux_field').hide();
  } else {
    $('tva_taux_field').show();
  }
}
document.observe('dom:loaded', function() {
  tvaSelected();
  $('journal_tva_id').observe('change', tvaSelected);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you've made a complete switch and aren't trying to use both jQuery and Prototype together (which can be done by the way).

Try this:

```
var rates = new Array();

<% for tva_rate in @tva_rates -%>

  rates.push(new Array(<%= tva_rate.id %>, '<%=h tva_rate.taux %>', '<%=h tva_rate.compte_id %>' ));

<% end -%>

function tvaSelected() {

  tva_id = $('#journal_tva_id').val(); // use id selector and val()

  show = 1;
  if (tva_id > 0){
    $.each(rates,function(idx,rate) {
        if (rate[0] == tva_id) {
            $('#journal_taux').val(rate[1]); // use id selector and val()
            $('#journal_compte_tva').val(rate[2]); // use id selector and val()
            show = 2;
        }
    });
}

  if (show == 1) {
    $('#tva_taux_field').hide(); // use id selector
  } else {
    $('#tva_taux_field').show(); // use id selector
  }
}

$(function() { // use short-hand for document.ready() instead of onload event observer
  tvaSelected();
  $('#journal_tva_id').change(tvaSelected); //use id and set up change handler
});
```

Comment: Hi Tvan, I've just tested your code and it's unfortunatly not working... I'm using Jquery-rails if it could help... Even the simple hide/show function isn't working.

Comment: What does Firebug show in the error console?  You do have jQuery included on the page and don't have Prototype included, correct?

Comment: Sorry my newbie question bug where could I verify that in firebug? Console says, rates.each is not a function.

Comment: I've found a way to make the get value part working. Changed for jQuery.each(rates, function(idx,rate){.... but hide and show part is not working... Anyone could help me with this one?